# Проблемы с реверс прокси nginx с nodejs прилоежнием. Centos8

Tags: mysql, node.js, nginx, centos8

Опишу, как я настраиваю свой удаленный сервер от digitalocean

1. Делаю дроплет на Centos 8
2. Вхожу в систему и меняю пароль
3. Создаю нового юзера и задаю пароль

   ```
   adduser shmzl

   passwd shmzl
   ```
4. Даю ему привилегию sudo

   ```
   gpasswd -a shmzl wheel
   ```
5. dnf update and dnf uprage
6. Отключаю на время SElinux и перезагружаю систему
7. установка и настройка firewalld

   ```
   dnf install firewalld -y

   systemctl start firewalld

   firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=(http, http, mysql, openvpn)

   firewall-cmd --reload (пока что его выключил)
   ```
8. Настройка подключению по публичному ключу и дублировании директории ssh пользователю shmzl
9. Захожу от имени пользователя shmzl
10. Активирую веб консоль

```
systemctl enable --now cockpit.socket
```

11. Закрываю доступ по паролю
12. Устанавливаю node js

```
sudo  dnf clean all

sudo dnf makecache fast (пишет, что неправильный аргумент fast, я делал, как в гайде расписано)

sudo dnf install -y gcc-c++ make

sudo dnf install nodejs
```

13. Создаю папку, пушу проект
14. Ставлю pm2

```
sudo npm install pm2@latest -g
```

15. Ставлю nginx

```
sudo dnf install nginx
```

16. Настраиваю файл nginx conf (скину текстом его после этого сообщения)

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

17. Создаю группу `WebAdmin`, включаю туда пользователя и nginx
18. создаю папку `/var/www` и кидаю туда проект, делаю разрешению права на эту папку `mkdir /var/www`
19. устанавливаю mysql, создаю базу test
20. захожу в папку с проектом

```
npm install

./node..../dbmigrate up

pm2 start app.js
```

21. так же я закинул страницы ошибок в папку с проектом
    Перехожу по своему домену и nginx выдает страницу ошибки (вот [ссылка](http://test.trinbox.ru), если что)

Вот мой nginx.conf:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        server_name  test.trinbox.ru;
        root         /var/www/cd-test;


        location / {
        proxy_read_timeout 5m; 
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

Вот error log nginx

```
2020/12/20 17:53:13 [error] 6496#0: *17 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 176.59.97.233, server: test.trinbox.ru, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:3000/", host: "test.trinbox.ru"
2020/12/20 17:53:13 [error] 6496#0: *17 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 176.59.97.233, server: test.trinbox.ru, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "test.trinbox.ru"
```

Почему два errora почти одинаковых в одно время? В папке есть еще `nginx.conf.default`, это может как связано?

Comment: Запускал проект локально, все работало. Приложение простое, просто выводиться количество просмотров сайта.

Comment: на сервере `curl http://localhost:3000` что показывает?

Comment: запустите app.js без pm2, сделайте пару запросов с локалхоста

Comment: @nörbörnën Когда сервер был запущен с помощью pm2 то писалось `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused` , а если я запускаю приложение с помощью команды `npm start app.js` и делаю `curl http://localhost:3000` , то все работает, как надо

Comment: ну, вот и нашли точку в которой проблема, дальше сами (в документацию пм2)

Comment: кстати, пускач `npm start app.js` выглядит странно

Comment: @nörbörnën Почему странно?

Comment: @nörbörnën Мне нужно сделать файл ecosystem? Я не понимаю, что не так с pm2

Comment: Почему два errora почти одинаковых в одно время — Если доменному имени соответствует несколько адресов, то все они будут использоваться по очереди (round-robin) (http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) `localhost` ресолвится в два адреса `127.0.0.1` (IPv4) и `::1` (IPv6) и nginx пробует оба